# BASIC SPRING: Foreign Keys and Relational Tables

Tags: java, spring, foreign-keys

I'm creating a simple Java-Spring project using MySQL server.
While creating tables on the database I see that Spring creates some sort of "relational tables".

[OneToMany, ManyToOne tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKSFx.png)

But all of them are empty.

I check the table "ticket" and the column gig_id (Foreign key) is filled with the right value.

[Foreign Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MrLu.png)

The system works.

Should I have both the tables filled, or leave it as Spring creates them?

Comment: I would not let spring or the underlying persistence manager generate the database. This does not usually happen in production.  What is the right thing to do depends on what your goals are. If you want to test something quickly, then of course you save time if you let spring generate the tables.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience It's better to have relationship on only one side

To ensure that only one relational table is created and to prevent Spring Boot from creating another table automatically, it's recommended to use only one side of the mapping for the relationship.

To accomplish this, you can use the mappedBy attribute on the non-owning side of the relationship mapping. For example, if you want to ignore the creation of the intermediate table for a @OneToMany relationship, you can add the mappedBy attribute to the @ManyToOne side of the relationship and specify the column name to map to: